# Can't use color value resource in style value res

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a newcomer in android development. Have no idea what's wrong with this. The color that I have been declared in colors.xml value res can't not be used in my styles.xml...

here is how I declared the color in colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="my_green">#59ab1b</color>
    <color name="app_bgcolor">#ededed</color>
    <color name="txt_grey">#707070</color>
</resources>
```

then when i try to put use it in my style xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="lbl_welcome">
        <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_green"</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

it's said like this:

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:textColor' with value '@color/
>    my_green"').

any idea?

thanks before!

Comment: make sure the styles.xml is in Project>>res>>values>>style.xml

Comment: i have put well the styles.xml in project>>res>values

Comment: yes, i will definitely accept the answers that helps and works.. :)

Comment: really sorry..
what a shame!
it was just because a typo in my code..
if you noticed, i shouldn't have a quotation mark there...
thanks Sam anyway.. i still up vote your answer though, because it's  a new knowledge for me.. 

sorry again..

Answer (score 5):

Hey I just noticed your item tag has a quote mark in the end, like this:

`<item name="android:textColor">@color/my_green"</item>`

and it should read like this:

`<item name="android:textColor">@color/my_green</item>`

without the " after my_green.

At least this way it works for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: hehe, I just had the EXACT same issue. (not very careful cutting and pasting from the Views XML that used to have it on my part)

Answer (score 1):

can you try this and tell me if it works

```
<resources>
    <color name="my_green">#ff59ab1b</color>
    <color name="app_bgcolor">#ffededed</color>
    <color name="txt_grey">#ff707070</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: it makes the error in styles.xml disappear..
but, more error comes in my layout file, main.xml.. where i also you used the color.. weird?!

Comment: the prefix **ff** is the alpha of the color. if you give somethin like **#4059ab1b** you will have a translusent effect. so may be you editor is insisting on this format.

Comment: could you be more clear, in fact if you don't give it by default, it assumed as '**ff**'

Comment: sorry just came back from lunch here
i mean, when i try your advice to put the prefix **ff** the error in my styles.xml disappear, but it give some others error in my xml layout file, in which i also use the color as some of my layout and widget attribute..

`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@color/my_green"
 >
<Button android:id="@+id/btn_preRegister"
  android:text="@string/btn_preRegister"
  android:textColor="@color/my_green" />`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both file are in the 'values' folder within 'res'

Answer (score -1):

use @android:color/your_color

eg. `<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/my_green</item>`